# Extracting name/value pairs from JSON with Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have this JSON code:

```
{
"success": 1,
"item": [
    {
        "itemId": "jogurt123",
        "name": "Jogurt",
        "description": "kajmak",
        "pictureUrl": "https://www.google.hr/images/srpr/logo11w.png",
        "categoryId": "mlijeko"
    }
],
"specs": [
    {
        "specId": "volumen",
        "value": "1",
        "unit": "litra"
    },
    {
        "specId": "mast",
        "value": "50",
        "unit": "%"
    }
]
```

}

I wonder how to extract name/value pairs into Strings using Java.
I would like to get the end result:

```
String name = "Jogurt"
String description = "kajmak"
etc...
```

I tried using JSONObject to create an object that contains this name/value pairs and I wanted to extract them then but in the following code

```
    String getParam(String code, String element){
    try {
        String base = this.getItembyID(code);
        JSONObject product = new JSONObject(base);
        String param = product.getString("name");
        return param;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error";
    }
    }
```

I get an exception saying that there is not an element "name" in the JSONObject when clearly there is. Any suggestions?

EDIT: The getItembyID method returns the JSON code written above in a string form. JSON code has been validated

Comment: Did you dump (toString) the `product` object to see what it looks like?  You need to understand the structure of a JSON structure before you can extract data from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

{ ->JSONObject

[-> JSONArray

You need to get the jsonObject inside the Jsonarray

Do like this

```
String getParam(String code, String element){
    try {
           String base = this.getItembyID(code);
           JSONObject product = new JSONObject(base);
          JSONArray jarray = product.getJSONArray("item");
         String param =  jarray.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
  return param;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error";
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `base` is the JSON you posted in your question, then your assumptions stated here

> I get an exception saying that there is not an element "name" in the
>   JSONObject when clearly there is.

are wrong. The JSON object you've shown contains only 3 elements: `success`, `item`, and `specs`. `item` is a JSON array with a single element, another JSON object. That JSON object contains a value named `name`.

You need to get *that* JSON object so that you can retrieve *that* value.

Or consider using a different JSON parsing library like Jackson or Gson that mostly does this for you based on some POJO class.

Comment: I modified my code to 
String getParam(String code, String element){
        try {
         String base = this.getItembyID(code);
   JSONObject product = new JSONObject(base);
   JSONArray item = product.getJSONArray("item");
   String param = (String) item.getString(1);
   return param;
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return "error";
  }
    }
But now I get another error JSONArray[1] not found. Why is that?

Comment: @MislavJavor Don't post code in comments. It's hard to read. `item` is a JSON array that contains a single JSON object, not a String, and not at index 1. The first element is at index 0.

Comment: Sorry for the code in comment, didn't know how else to do it. Thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 1):

If u have java classes for particular data u are getting in form of json.
Then it would be easy to extract data by using jackson library. 
[ Download:  [http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.2.3/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar]](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.2.3/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar)

then Your code will be:

```
public String getParam(String code, String element) {

    String base = this.getElementById(code);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Product product = mapper.readValue(base, Product.class);

    // this will return name of product
    return product.getItem()[0].getName();
}
```